# Custom LinearLayout with an Icon

Tags: android, android-layout

I got a bunch of form controls that all show an Icon to the left, like so:

[image]

For this I have this code:

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_edittext_height"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/icon_edittext_marginRight"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/icon_edittext_margintop"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_location_city_black_24dp"/>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/create.data.city.layout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            >
                            <AutoCompleteTextView
                                android:id="@+id/create.data.city"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="@string/create_event_city"
                                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                />

                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    </FrameLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
```

Now because I have around 20 controls, I dont want to repeat the:

```
<LinearLayout> 
    <ImageView/> 
    <FrameLayout> 
         ...content....
    </FrameLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

schema 20 times, but I would like to do something like this:

```
<MycustomLayout>
    <EditText .../>
</MycustomLayout>

<MycustomLayout>
    <Spinner ... />
</MycustomLayout>
```

So basically I want to create a custom Layout that extends Linear, and I want to be able to use it in the same way that I use LinearLayout, while having an icon prepended at all times.

Comment: Good! What stage are you at in writing your custom layout?

Comment: I created one that extends the LinearLayout, put an image on it, but dont know how to make it so that the content within the <MycustomLayout> goes within the inner FrameLayout

Answer (score 0):

You can try using include tag in your layout to include the part which is repeating. Or if that doesn't work you can try something like this:

```
public class CustomControl extends LinearLayout {

    public CustomControl (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, this);
    }
}
```

Where custom_layout is the layout for you custom view.
Then you can just do in your xml:

```
<CustomControl />
```

UPD:
In order to add child views in xml just override onFinishInflate and add views like this:

```
    protected void onFinishInflate() {      
        View[] children = detachChildren(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
           this.addView(children[i]);
        }
```

Comment: this does not answer my question

Answer (score 0):

No need to add too much layouts. Just try to use this...

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/create.data.city.layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/create.data.city"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="City"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location_city_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: this does not achieve the same result

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself like so:

```
public class IconFieldLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {


    private Drawable mDefaultDrawable;

    public IconFieldLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public IconFieldLinearLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public IconFieldLinearLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public IconFieldLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
        mDefaultDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tv_avatar_default);
        initAttr(context, attrs);
    }

    private void initAttr(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                    R.styleable.IconFieldLinearLayout, 0, 0);
            Drawable icon = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.IconFieldLinearLayout_icon);
            a.recycle();
            initIcon(context, icon);
        }
        else {
            initIcon(context, mDefaultDrawable);
        }
    }

    private void initIcon(Context context, Drawable icon) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));
        int dimension = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.icon_edittext_height);
        int marginRight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.icon_edittext_marginRight);
        int marginTop = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.icon_edittext_margintop);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, dimension);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, marginTop, marginRight, 0);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(icon);
        addView(imageView, layoutParams);
    }


}
```

Did not really need to put the FrameLayout in there.